# How can I run a Rmarkdown file in VScode?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm using VSCode for R programming. As I try different ways of plotting my data, I thought it might be a nice idea to use a Rmd file to get track of what I tried but my problem is I can't make this work.

I have `rmarkdown` and `knitr` installed but when I knit my .Rmd file, I get this output:

```
[VSC-R] 4.1_main.Rmd process started
==> rmarkdown::render('c:\\Users\\tl100\\Documents\\R\\thesis_figures\\4.1_main.Rmd')
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).

Execution halted

[VSC-R] 4.1_main.Rmd process exited with exit code 1
[VSC-R] terminating R process
```

So I tried to install pandoc: `installr::install.pandoc()`, but I get another error message:

```
> installr::install.pandoc()
trying URL 'https://github.com/'
downloaded 201 KB


The file was downloaded successfully into:
 C:\Users\tl100\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbBZMs/github.com

Running the installer now...
Die Version von C:\Users\tl100\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbBZMs\github.com ist mit der ausgeführten Windows-Version nicht kompatibel. Überprüfen Sie die Systeminformationen des Computers, und wenden Sie sich anschließend an den Herausgeber der Software.

Installation status:  FALSE . Removing the file:
 C:\Users\tl100\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbBZMs/github.com
 (In the future, you may keep the file by setting keep_install_file=TRUE) 
Warning message:
In shell(install_cmd, wait = wait, ...) :
  'C:\Users\tl100\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbBZMs/github.com' execution failed with error code 1
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
```

However, I could successfully install pandoc via the msi installer from its github page (https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/3.1.9). Then, I check if pandoc is availalbe in my PATH variable:

[image]

But still, if I run `rmarkdown::pandoc_available()`, it says `FALSE`.

So is there a way of running Rmd files from VSCode, or do I have to use RStudio instead?

I would very much appreciate your help :-)